# Bounded martingale that does not converge in $L^1$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces, martingales

Given $p>1$, if a martingale $M_n$ is bounded in $L^p$ (meaning $\sup_n E(|M_n|^p)<\infty$), then it converges almost surely and in $L^p$ to some $M_\infty$. However, if the martingale is only bounded in $L^1$, then one can only state for sure that it converges almost surely.

> Consider a bounded martingale (meaning there exists $A>0$ such that for all $n$, $|M_n|\leq A$ a.s). Must $M_n$ converge in $L^1$ ?

If $M_n$ is bounded, it's bounded in $L^p$ for every $p>1$, so it must converge in $L^p$ for any $p>1$. I haven't been able to prove or disprove convergence in $L^1$, hence my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is well known (e.g. see Theorem 1.3 of [this](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/~matsr/ProbII/Lec3.pdf)) : $M_n$ converges almost surely and in $L^1$ to $M_\infty$ iff $M_n$ is uniformly integrable, i.e.:

$$\lim_{K\rightarrow\infty}[\sup_{n}E[|M_n|1_{M_n\geq K}]=0.$$

Since $|M_n|\leq A$, then yes, $M_n$ will converge to $M_\infty$ both almost surely and in $L^1$.

Comment: I haven't been introduced to uniform integrability (and I don't think I will be). But I do know that there's convergence in $L^1$ iff there is some integrable $X_\infty$ such that $M_n = E(X_\infty|\mathcal F_n)$. Do you think I really need the concept of uniform integrability to prove convergence in $L^1$ ?

Comment: As a matter of fact, since $M_n\xrightarrow{a.s} M_\infty$, $|M_\infty|\leq A$ a.s. Fix some $n$. For all $k\geq 0$, $M_n = E(M_{n+k}|\mathcal F_n)$.  By the DCT for conditional expectation, $M_n = E(M_\infty|\mathcal F_n)$. So $M_n$ converges in $L^1$.

Comment: @GabrielRomon: Yes see (iv) of Theorem 1.3 in the above link